# Why can't I import my Azure DevOps repo to a new Azure DevOps repo?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, repository, devops

I'm trying to create a new repository in Azure DevOps based on an old repository also in Azure DevOps, but the transfer is not working.

The new repository is under a new project and organization. When I create it and go to Repos, I see this:

[image]

It seems like I have two options for importing the old repository over to this one:

- Push an existing repository from command line.
- Import a repository.

When I try to push an existing repository from the command line, I copy and paste the commands it gives me to the command line (PowerShell) while in the root of the project directory on my local computer (where the .git folder and .sln file are). The command is:

```
git remote add origin https://holland-and-barnes@dev.azure.com/holland-and-barnes/Holland%20and%20Barnes/_git/Holland%20and%20Barnes
```

Running this command, it tells me:

```
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=(push|fetch)]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from
```

...and then:

```
git push -u origin --all
```

Running this command, it tells me:

```
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

And yet, back at dev.azure.com, it still says "Holland and Barnes is empty. Add some code!"

So I try the second method (importing from the old repository).

I click "Import" and it brings up the "Import a Git repository" popup:

[image]

I keep the repository type as Git and I enter the following for the Clone URL:

```
https://wardrop.visualstudio.com/Holland%20And%20Barnes/_git/Holland%20And%20Barnes
```

I get this directly from the Clone Repository popup of the old repository (Repos >> click on Clone):

[image]

I check "Requires Authentication" and enter my username and Password. I click "Import".

But it tells me in pink at the top:

```
Import request cannot be processed due to one of the following reasons:

Clone URL is incorrect.
Clone URL requires authorization
```

[image]

I am sure I'm entering my credentials properly. I copied the clone URL directly from the old repository. What else can I do?

Answer (score 5):

> What else can I do?

The easiest way to import repo is to use import option in Azure Devops(Same as your method 2).

But from your screenshot, it seems that you are using the `UserName and Password`.

If yes, you could try to use PAT ([Use personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)).

You could grant the **Full Access** to the PAT and check if it could work.

On my side, if I use `UserName+ Password`, I get the same error message. But `UserName+PAT` can work fine

Another way is  Git command.

You could try the following Scripts:

```
git clone https://xxx.visualstudio.com/Holland%20And%20Barnes/_git/Holland%20And%20Barnes

cd xxxx/xx/Holland%20And%20Barnes

git remote add origin https://xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxx

git push -u origin --all
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Kevin. Your answer *sounds* like it would work, but I didn't get a chance to test it. I ended up taking a different approach. I cloned the new repository into a new folder. Then copied the existing source code to the new folder. Did a git add . Committed everything. That seemed to work for my purposes. I'll come back to this in the future if I need to try this again (I'd have to figure out what my PAT is).

Comment: @gib65 You could refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page PAT(personal access tokens) is an authentication method in azure devops. In most cases, it will be more effective. Next time you can try it and wait for your good news. Thanks

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT.. Hi Kevin.. Could you suggest if there is any way to do this process using Azure DevOps Rest API's?..you can suggest me in this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/67585691/13460189   thankyou

Comment: I confirm this works. I first used my password and had the exact error as the OP. Then I generated a PAT, which I used and the import was successful.